# Logout with Rest Template in Spring Security Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, resttemplate

I'm writing a client for my application. Spring stack is Spring 4 and Spring Security 4 (main parts).

I try to logout from my application in the following way:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("_csrf=" + csrfToken,
                                             httpHeaders);
restTemplate.postForEntity(appUrl + "/logout", entity, String.class);
```

A `RestTemplate` object is created in the following way (before login of course):

```
new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
```

But I get the following exception on the server:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:207) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:374) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352)
```

I was getting the following exception when I tried to login in the app. The only
way I managed to do it is getting login page and getting CSRF token from there. I tried to get token from the server in the following way and return it to the client:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/csrf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String csrf(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return ((CsrfToken) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName())).getToken();
}
```

But with this token I was getting the same exception all the time.

Now I want to implement logout in any way at least but notes related to proper login with `RestTemplate` is appreciated too. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: adding security config

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final UserDetailsService splittingRolesUserDetails;
    private final AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(DataSource dataSource, UserDetailsService splittingRolesUserDetails,
                          AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.splittingRolesUserDetails = splittingRolesUserDetails;
        this.accessDeniedHandler = accessDeniedHandler;
    }

    // overrides role prefix in case .access() in httpSecurity configuration
    // just because it is needed in the task. hasRole() won't work
    // as there are used different voters in AffirmativeBased.
    // link to the related issue on GitHub:
    // https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3701
    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select user_name, password, true from user where username=?");
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(splittingRolesUserDetails);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/csrf").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/ticket/event**").access("hasRole('" + Role.BOOKING_MANAGER.toString() + "')")
                .anyRequest().access("hasRole('" + Role.REGISTERED_USER.toString() + "')")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/event")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .userDetailsService(splittingRolesUserDetails);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception when you login and how did you login,did you save the cookie?  and did you add the cookie to header when you request logout url ?> "I was getting the following exception when I tried to login in the app"

Comment: @chaoluo For login I was getting the same exception as I'm getting doing logout, I didn't save the cookie. When performing logout I'm setting X-CSRF-TOKEN header (although it is not needed here as far as I understand), adding "_csrf=" form parameter and setting Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Http is a stateless protocol, If you want to implement your own client, you should request with cookie(e.g JSESSIONID) . BUT why you not changing anther authentication for your client, (e.g HTTP Basic/Bearer Authentication) ?

Comment: @chaoluo I'm creating a RestTemplate object with this call: new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()). And I'm able to login into the application and perform some requests. So I guest this is the thing adding JSESSIONID. Sorry, I don't quite get it how can I change authentication on client?

Comment: The server should also do some changes to support Basic authentication.

Comment: @chaoluo Got it:) I guess I don't get it right but as for me the approach I'm using is more secure? I mean using csrf.

Comment: are you able to login or whenever you request a token it simply throws an error?

Comment: @Coder No, I was not. Actually I ended adding `CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()` and /csrf call that returns csrf token. Then I send this token while login, it changes and I use a new one in further operations till logout. It doesn't seem to change farther

Answer (score 0):

No need to send your token from an endpoint that is not secured, that contradicts the principle for which the token is used in the first place. You can store your token in a cookie with HTTP only access by adding this to your config:

```
.and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

You can then retrieve it from a cookie named XSRF-TOKEN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not sure I get it right. To my mind csrf token is used to protect server from unauthorized requests. Why should be endpoint like browser or RestTemplate object be secured for this purpose? Also what the difference between my configuration and the own you suggest? As I understand csrf token will be verified anyway but this time it will be stored in cookie having the other name.

Comment: I think you are getting the csrf thing wrong. csrf token is used to protect against cross site request forgery, which take advantage of the server side session, and tries to mimic a request to either steal information or cause damage. If the token is available through your endpoint then you are vulnerable to a csrf attack. A cookie can be accessed only by your app.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation then! I guess I really should dig deeper here. But I've tried your solution and it doesn't seem to work with logout although I'm able to make login more accurate using my /api/csrf method. I get the same error. No I set X-XSRF-TOKEN header. Am I doing something wrong?